# sending objects over spring to gwt

Tags: hibernate, spring, gwt

This days I force with an application that I need to use GWT as presentation layer.  I've learned some things that can help me to handle my project but now I have a problem that I can't found a good solution for that.

The problem is that when I try to send an object that I retrieved from MySQL with Hibernate by spring o presentation layer(GWT) I get this exception:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = [codes.shared.question@7e14d761, codes.shared.question@16165c24, codes.shared.question@15fb4ad0]
```

I should mention I want to send a class that named Exam and this class have a list of question class.

I will be thankful realy for any bits of help to get rid me of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Data Transfer Objects, cause only DTOs can be transferred to GWT client side.

You should create ExamDto and QuestionDto and after receiving Exam object from MySQL you had to convert it to ExamDto.

On client side you'll be operating only DTOs. If you would like to save Exam to MySQL you should convert ExamDto to Exam.

To convert POJOs to DTOs and back you should use [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/).

To use Dozer you need to map DTOs and POJOs using Dozer mappings. I use [Custom Mappings Via Dozer XML Files](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mappings.html).

The best tutorial that describes GWT-Hibernate relation : [Using GWT with Hibernate](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html)

Also, I'v created convertor class DozerGenerator and use it in my applications. For example, I have 2 RPCs - one is to find users, second - to save user.

```
    public UserDto findUserById(long id) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    //userService.findUserById(long id) returns User object and than 
    //you need to convert it to UserDto to transfer to client.
        return DozerGenerator.appUserEntityToDto(userService.findUserByID(id));
    }
    //here, you converts UserDto to User
    public Long saveUser(UserDto userDto) throws IllegalArgumentException {                
        return userService.saveUser(DozerGenerator.appUserDtoToEntity(mapper, userDto));
 }
```

And here its DozerGenerator class:

```
public class DozerGenerator {

    /* User <-> UserDto */
        public static User appUserDtoToEntity(DozerBeanMapper mapper, UserDto dto) {
            return mapper.map(dto, User.class);
        }

        public static UserDto appUserEntityToDto(DozerBeanMapper mapper, User user) {
            return mapper.map(user, UserDto.class);
        }

        public static List<UserDto> appUserListEntityToDto(DozerBeanMapper mapper, List<User> users) {
            List<UserDto> models = new ArrayList<UserDto>();
            for (User u : users) {
                models.add(DozerGenerator.appUserEntityToDto(mapper, u));
            }
            return models;
        }

        public static List<User> appUserListDtoToEntity(DozerBeanMapper mapper, List<UserDto> dtos) {
            List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
            for (UserDto u : dtos) {
                users.add(DozerGenerator.appUserDtoToEntity(mapper, u));
            }
            return users;
        }
}
```

Also, I use GWT+Spring+JPA+Hibernate in my apps without any special libraries as spring4gwt and gilead(hibernate4gwt) and it works fine.

You also can find some info about your error here [Issue 3296](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3296)

Answer (score 0):

Have you `join fetch`ed the list with the exam, I think it is a lazy collection which is not initialized (populated) yet